# Android Realm how to check if Realm has been initialized

Tags: android, realm

I've a problem with the initialization of Realm.
I get systematically an error with :

```
        Realm realminstance = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
```

I caught this exception :

```
No default RealmConfiguration was found. Call setDefaultConfiguration() first
```

I know I have to init Realm before using it, but could you tell me how can I check if Realm is initialized ?
It doesn't works with:

```
if(Realm.getDefaultConfiguration == null){...}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: This shouldn't even occur if you set the default configuration in `application.onCreate()`, although `getFilesDir()` can return `null` sometimes on first run which can definitely screw it over....

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet here should work: https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#controlling-the-lifecycle-of-realm-instances

```
// Setup Realm in your Application
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfiguration);
    }
}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    private Realm realm;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        realm.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the problem is that I can't initialize Realm configuration until the user has not logged. (I manage multiple user application). So my mainActivity is loaded, and the loginActivity is loaded after. And I have to test in my mainActivity, if Realm is initialized, and if not, I force the user to log in

Comment: @ElFrancky Honestly, you may as well manage a `boolean` flag in your custom application after you call `Realm.setDefaultInstance()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Why not, It's a solution :) thank you

Comment: It would be great if Realm Team add a method like "Realm.isInit()" which return a boolean ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a try catch block. I initially initialised my realm in the application class and used it in a content provider and sync adapter but the provider is created before the application apparently so I was forced to do a try catch in all 3 to avoid whatever race condition may occur (couldn't find documentation for what gets created first amongst the components).

```
`try{
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
} catch (Exception e){
Realm.init()
//Configuration, schema, migration, and encryption details come here
//Now we get the default instance: again.
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
}`
```